# What are the advantages of using urban airship over C2DM

Tags: android, android-c2dm, urbanairship.com

The title pretty much sums it up. 
What's the difference between those services exactly and what are the advantages of using one over another ?
I'd like to know what's the difference between UA and APN of apple as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Convenience I guess I havent used it but it seems it will work on both iPhone and android.

C2DM is android(2.2) specify. 
APN is specify to iphone.

So you will have to work a bit more if your app is on both android and iphone. Urban airship seems to solve this extra step.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read urban airship gives push support to 1.6 and above if you go pro. Android c2dm only works on 2.2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

1- Allows the devices running platforms lower than 2.2 ( API level 8 ) to receive push notifications.

2- Handles many requests between the device and the server on behalf of the developer (e.g. the registration tying an APID (Android Push ID -  is the Urban Airship ID of a device to which a message can be pushed from the Urban Airship API ) to your application happens automatically ).

3- Broadcasts the messages to all the registered devices ( of course you can do it just by looping on all the registered devices, but eventually Urban Airship still does it for you ).